# Pylance reportGeneralTypeIssues: Pylance expects 0 positional arguments in `pd.Timestamp`

Tags: pylance

Any idea what is going on here? I know the code works.

I actually commonly encounter random pylance irregularities. More generally, how should I debug this? I see the error message is "Expected 0 positional arguments", which I disagree with for the `pd.Timestamp` constructor.

EDIT: I clicked away, typed some spaces, and the error disappeared.

[image]